# Python3 encode & decode issue

Tags: python, python-3.x, unicode, encoding, character-encoding

I'm Korean and making web scraping program on my college site which consist of Korean contents 
However, when I scrap some contents of table in this site, the result looks like this :

```
16/01/27  (2.16 ¸¶°¨)2016ÇÐ³âµµ 1ÇÐ±â ÀÌÈ­¿©´ë ´ëÇÐ¿ø ...
16/01/27  (1.29 ¸¶°¨)2016ÇÐ³âµµ 1ÇÐ±â ÀÌÈ­¿©´ë(ÇÐºÎ) ÇÐ...
16/01/27  [º¸°ÇÁø·á¼Ò] Áø·á½Ã°£ ´ÜÃà ¾Ë¸²
16/01/26  2016ÇÐ³âµµ 1ÇÐ±â ±³³» ±Ù·ÎÀåÇÐ ½ÅÃ» ¾È³»
16/01/26  [½ºÆ®·¹½ºÅ¬¸®´Ð] 16³â 2¿ù ¸í»óÇÁ·Î±×·¥ Âü°¡ÀÚ...
16/01/26  [¿µ¾î°­ÀÇ ¼ö°­ Àü·«] ¿µ¾î ÇÁ·¹Á¨Å×ÀÌ¼Ç,¿µ¾î ...
16/01/26  ¼­¿ï´ëÇÐ±³ Àü±â¡¤µµ½Ã°¡½º ¿¡³ÊÁö »ç¿ëÁ¤º¸ ¾È...
16/01/26  (2.3 ¸¶°¨)2016ÇÐ³âµµ 1ÇÐ±â °øÁÖ´ë ÇÐÁ¡±³·ù ¾È...
16/01/26  (2.3 ¸¶°¨)2016ÇÐ³âµµ 1ÇÐ±â ¾ÆÁÖ´ë ´ëÇÐ¿ø ÇÐÁ¡...
16/01/26  (1.29 ¸¶°¨)2016ÇÐ³âµµ 1ÇÐ±â ¾ÆÁÖ´ë(ÇÐºÎ) ÇÐÁ¡...
16/01/25  [½ÅÃ»] 2015 µ¿°è SNUìÑ Ãë¾÷Ä·ÇÁ
16/01/25  µ¿°è¹æÇÐ ¼ÅÆ²¹ö½º ¿îÇàÇöÈ²
16/01/25  2016. 1ÇÐ±â ´ëÇÐ¿µ¾î1, ´ëÇÐ¿µ¾î2 ´ã´ç±³¼ö º¯...
```

It looks like an alien language. When I print the `type` of these alien sentence, all sentences are `type 'str'`
As far as I know, default encoding of Python 3 is unicode so I don't have to use `encode()` or `decode()` function as I did in Python 2.
But I don't know why this kind of thing happens.
I really want to let you know the site URL, but this page could be accessed only by authorized user. 
I want your advices, thanks.

P.S Only this page shows like this. When I scrap other Korean site, it didn't happens.

Comment: Does that Web page have a proper encoding specification in the `<head>`? Look for a line that starts: `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type"` and see what it has for the `charset` attribute. Also use your Web browser's developer tools (eg `Tools/Page Info` in Firefox) to see what encoding it specifies in the `Content-Type` header for that page.

Comment: `str == System encoding` and `unicode == Real Character` Got a lot smilar questions here.

Comment: @PM2Ring When I look around page source using Chrome development tool, it shows `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ksc5601">` at the top... <br>So, I edit my code like this : `content.encode("ksc5601").decode("ksc5601")` but it shows errors : `UnicodeEncodeError: 'euc_kr' codec can't encode character '\xf6' in position 1: illegal multibyte sequence`

Comment: After some research, `ksc5601` is character set, and `euc_kr` is character encoding.. But I have no idea how to deal with it..

Comment: You have to decode the encoded bytes to Unicode objects. So what does `content.decode("euc_kr")` do?

Comment: You may find this article helpful: [Pragmatic Unicode](http://nedbatchelder.com/text/unipain.html), which was written by SO veteran Ned Batchelder.

Comment: Since content is the `type <str>`, it doesn't have `decode()`. What I did is `content.encode('euc_kr', 'ignore').decode('euc_kr')` but it shows same result.

Comment: You left out how you do the screen scraping and the code you used.  Whatever function you use reads bytes from the web page.  If it returns `content` as a 3.x string, then it is decoding the byes with the encoding specified in the web page headers.  If the web sites lies, which happens,then you get weird results. you get a mess like the above.  The stdlib `urllib.request.urlopen(...).read()` returns the page body as bytes (headers are also available).  You are left to decide whether to decode as text or image or ??? and if as text, which decoding to use  -- the one in the header or another.

Comment: `.encode('latin1').decode('euc_kr')` will fix the content, so whatever code used to scrape the page is using `latin1` (or something similar like `cp1252`) instead of the correct encoding.

Comment: Can you post your scraping code and the url?

Comment: @MarkTolonen oh my god..............`.encode('latin1').decode('euc_kr')` works!!!! Reaally appreciate it!. But how could that happens?...Why should I encode string into `latin1` first??

Comment: You stated "Only this page shows like this. When I scrape other Korean sites, it didn't happen", so it is likely that particular website is reporting the wrong encoding for its pages, or maybe that particular page.  The encoding may actually be `Windows-1252`, which is a default for some Windows systems.  If the site is encoding in `euc_kr` but you are decoding in `latin1` or similar encoding, you have to re-encode with the wrong encoding and then decode with the correct one.

Comment: @MarkTolonen I can't understand 100% what you said. I think I have to study more about encoding and decoding. Thanks. :)

Comment: Here's a good presentation: http://nedbatchelder.com/text/unipain.html

Comment: Ok. I watched youtube video, and understand almost of contents. But according to http://pythoncentral.io/encoding-and-decoding-strings-in-python-3-x/, string cannot be encoded and after decoded with different character encoding format. (See `nonlat.encode('utf-16').decode('utf-8')` occurs errors). But how could `.encode('latin1').decode('euc_kr')` works?

Comment: @MarkTolonen Mark, I have some problems when I do run this code in my Raspberry pi. Could you please advise me about above my comment and this problem? http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/42088/raspberry-pi-2-encoding-problems-which-not-occur-in-mac-os-x. Thanks, in advance

Comment: `.encode('latin1').decode('euc_kr')` worked because you had a Unicode string that was decoded with the `latin1` encoding, which was incorrect due to what looks like bad configuration on either the webpage or your program.  You didn't show code.  `.encode('latin1')` reversed the bad decode, giving you the original byte string, then `.decode('euc_kr')` decoded it back to the correct Unicode string.  Your other question looks like your `nonlat` string contains non-latin1 characters, so encoding in latin1 doesn't work.  You tried to make it work by ignoring errors, but that just drops bytes.

Comment: 1. You said, "you had a Unicode string that was decoded with the latin1 encoding," --> But How did you know that my unicode string is decoded with latin1?            2. "Your other question looks like your nonlat string contains non-latin1 characters," --> But it is same page and same crawling code with above....